# The class for my keyListener wont allow me to implement the key listener

Tags: java

the problem is in the line public class keyPressed implements KeyListener{
    it tells me to make it abstract but i know that is not needed.  Please any advice to why this is so or how to properly make this work thanks

```
    package GUI;
        import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Font;
        import java.awt.GridLayout;
        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import Data.TileList;


        import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
        import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
        public class MainUI implements Runnable {
            public JPanel gameGrid = new JPanel();
            private JFrame gameBoard;
            private int row = 4;
            private int col = 1;
            int boardSize = row * col;
            public MainUI(){
            }
            @Override
            public void run(){
                gameBoard = new JFrame("BrickGame");
                JButton st = new JButton("Start");
                Font fontst0 = st.getFont();
                Font fontst1 = fontst0.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, fontst0.getSize()*14);
                st.setFont(fontst1);
                gameBoard.add(gameGrid);
                gameGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
                st.addActionListener(new StartGame(this));
                gameGrid.add(st);
                JLabel txt = new JLabel();
                txt.setText("<HTML><body><H1>Instructions</H1><p>Click the 'start' button to start the game" +
                        "<br>Type the letters in the bricks to make a bric dissapear. After all bricks are gone the game is over.<p></body></HTML>");
                gameGrid.add(txt);
                gameBoard.setVisible(true);
                gameBoard.pack();
            }

                public void StartGame(){
                gameGrid.removeAll();
                gameGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,col));
                gameBoard.add(gameGrid);
                for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
                //String x = TileList.Letters[i] + "";
                //JButton tile = new JButton(x);
                    JButton tile = new JButton(new TileList(TileList.Letters[i]).getLetter() + "");
                    tile.setBackground(Color.red);
                    gameGrid.add(tile);
                }
                gameBoard.setFocusable(true);
                //here i am trying to addd the class of keypressed to the jframe.
                gameBoard.addKeyListener(new keyPressed());
                gameBoard.add(gameGrid);
                gameBoard.pack();
            }

        }






        package GUI;
        import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
        import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

         //the problem is  in the implements line below it tells me to make it abstract but that is not needed.
        public class keyPressed implements KeyListener{

        public keyPressed(){    
        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to implement ``keyReleased(KeyEvent e);``. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong. You have a class implementing an interface, and you're not implementing all the interface methods. You need to fix this by adding the third method, keyReleased. The API would tell you which methods you need, and in the future you will want to have a look there when you have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class keyPressed implements KeyListener{

            public keyPressed(){    
            }
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }
  }
```

`KeyListener` has three methods and you have implemented only 2 .Either implement the remaining methods or mark your class as `abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use only 2 methods the you have to use **keyAdapter**[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html):

```
   public class adapter implements KeyAdapter{

        @Override
        public keyPressed(KeyEvent key){ 

          //action...   

        }

       @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {

         //action

        }
```

}

Note that:

The **KeyListener** is interface.

*If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile.*